# Use Solr Length Filter, but keep some words

Tags: solr, lucene

We are using Solr to index some consumer goods descriptions, and our lexical analysis showed that it's safe to discard words with lenght < 4 (`<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="4" max="25" />`). We were able to provide better query results.

However, we are missing some meaningful words, such as GPS, LCD, LED, that we would like to keep.

Does Solr provides a filter that has this kind of functionality (discard short words, but if it is into an exception list, keep it)? Or I will need to specialize LengthFilter to achieve what I want?

I also thought to use a SynonymFiler to "convert" the token (ex.: LCD => liquid_crystal_display) before the LengthFilter. Any thoughts about this solution?

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about removing "nearly" all words in a filter chain with less than four letters.

You could use the [SynonymFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-SynonymFilter) for this. You even could use two SynonymFilter in the chain. First to make your words longer, second to switch back to original. Drawback: with only one SynonymFilter you can not use wildcards like `LC?` because wildcard search [does not use the filter chain](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2011/11/29/whats-with-lowercasing-wildcard-multiterm-queries-in-solr/).

Other possibility: Use [PatternReplaceFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-PatternReplaceFilter) to replace all your "to short" words with a stopword and add [StopFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-StopFilter) to your filter chain (possible a replacement with an empty word would be enough).